# How can I create a Dropdown Box for quantity where min. is 1 and max is set by a variable? (PHP)

Tags: php, e-commerce

was wondering if anyone had any idea if this was possible.

For an e-commerce site, there is a variable for max quantity allowed, let's just say its $maxqty.

On the checkout page, we have an input box for quantity.  We want to change this to a dropdown box, but each item has a different limit ($maxqty).

Is there a way to create a dropdown box with a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of $maxqty.

Specific Example:
Item #1, Max Qty = 5
Item #1 at Checkout Box, Quantity Drop Down would show choices for 1,2,3,4,5

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Thanks for all the quick and awesome responses - going to give this a shot!

Answer (score 2):

[select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tags in html are used to create dropdown list, which on checkout/submission of form, will give you the selected value in php.

Example:

```
 <select>
    <?php
   for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)  {
    echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
   } ?>
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

should be easy, you can place max qty in a variable , and then loop from 1 to that max qty, creating an option each time like e.g.

```
<? php
   for($i=1;$i<=$item_max;$i++)
   {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the max from querystring. It could also be assigned by other ways

```
<?php

  $maxQty = (int) $_GET['max_qty'];

?>

<select name="quantity">

<?php

 for($i=1; $i<=$maxQty; $i++)
   echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";

?>

</select>
```

OUTPUT

```
<select name="quantity">
   <option value='1'>1</option>
   <option value='2'>2</option>
   <option value='3'>3</option>
   <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This really depends a lot on your setup, that is how your form elements are generated.
You can just generate the select options through a for loop

```
<select name="quantity>
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=$maxqty;$i++) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```

Note that this intermixing of php in your html code is generally ill-advised and should be preferably separated